# Pycharm's "Attach to Local Process" Won't Connect

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm having troubles getting PyCharm to connect to a local process.  I cloned this project, https://github.com/fogleman/Minecraft and ran it from a terminal.  Then, I went into PyCharm and ran "Attach to local process" while selecting Python 2.7 as the debug interpreter.  Unfortunately, PyCharm just continues to try and connect to the client which I presume is the application.

I'm running this on Sierra (10.12.5), would appreciate any help, thanks!

[image: Pycharm won't connect]